# XmlInputFormat for Apache Flink

Tags: xml, mahout, apache-flink

Is there something similar to [Mahout's XmlInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/66f164057e322d2e63ea02c35c9e30c3969e80b1/integration/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/text/wikipedia/XmlInputFormat.java) but for Flink?

I have a large XML file and I want to extract specific elements. In my case it's a wikipedia dump and I need to get all `<page>` tags.

I.e. if I have a file

```
<mediawiki>
  <siteinfo>...</siteinfo>
  <page>...</page>
  <page>...</page>
  <page>...</page>
</mediawiki>
```

I want to get all 3 records `<page>...</page>` to be used in mappers. Ideally it should be valid XML, something that the xpath query `/mediawiki/page` would return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mahout's XmlInputFormat extends Hadoop's TextInputFormat.
Flink has generic wrappers for Hadoop InputFormats such that the XmlInputFormat should also be supported.

To read data with Hadoop InputFormats you can do:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> input =
  env.readHadoopFile(new TextInputFormat(), LongWritable.class, Text.class, textPath);
```

See the [documentation](http://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.8/hadoop_compatibility.html) for details.